# use REGEX value from MYSQL database

Tags: jquery, regex, codeigniter

I am storing regex `/Page [0-9]+ of [0-9]+/g` as a string in `mysql database with codeigniter web framework`.In my code if i use static value of `pattern` then it's working but if i replace `pattern` value from `database stored regex value` then it's not working.If i compare both string `static pattern with db stored value` using `if condition` then it says it's equal.

```
data = ["Page 1 of 10","test1","test2"];
pattern = /Page [0-9]+ of [0-9]+/g
for(k=0;k<data.length;k++){
    res = data[k].match(pattern);
    if(res){
        alert();
    }

}
```

Comment: Once you get your regex back from the database are you changing it back from a string to a Regexp object ?

Comment: @Karan Shishoo  no i am not changing